# Differentiate multi-variable max function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(a,b,c,d) = \max(a-b,-(a-c),-(a-d))$ where $\max(\cdot,\cdot,\cdot)$ is the maximum function, i.e., $max(3,4,6) = 6$, and $a,b,c,d$ are variables. Is it possible to compute the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $a,b,c,d$ respectively?

Comment: To find the partial derivative, we must know the output of max() function. Are there any constraints for a,b,c,d?

Comment: No constraints, $a,b,c,d$ take real values.

Comment: We have
$$f(a, b, c, d) =
2 \max \left(a, \frac {b + \max(c, d)} 2 \right) -
 a - b,$$
so all the cases boil down to differentiating the piecewise linear function $\max(x, x_0)$.